# Fabric JS: How to prevent scaling active group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

in Fabric JS when an object or multiple objects is/are selected, it's possible to scale them. Either in the corner (with aspects) or only width/height.

Is it possible to allow this only if an object is selected and prevent this if multiple objects are selected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you select multiple objects on the canvas, it essentially behaves like a Fabricjs Group. You can disable scaling for a group using `lockScalingX` and `lockScalingY` properties.

Now to access this group formed on selection, you can use the canvas `selection:created` event. Below is the sample code:

```
canvas.on('selection:created',function(ev){
    ev.target.set({
        lockScalingX: true,
        lockScalingY: true
    });
});
```

Above code disables scaling specifically for groups formed on user selection and not the groups that might have been added to the canvas by you. If you want to disable scaling globally for any group, then you can do that in following way:

```
fabric.Group.prototype.lockScalingX = true;
fabric.Group.prototype.lockScalingY = true;
```

You can find a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n9z58nuk/2/

Comment: Thanks! Do you if it's also possible to prevent scaling multiple objects to small, if some the selected objects hava minScaleLimit? Because in my case with latest FabricJS the minScaleLimit of Objects is ignored if they are selected in a group.

Comment: Yes, minScaleLimit is not honored in the case you mentioned. I think what you could do is find the minimum minScaleLimit amongst the selected objects and set that for the group made by selection.

Comment: You can also set `hasControls: false` to hide all scaling and rotation controls.

Comment: The `.target` property is deprecated since fabric v4